# How to draw a Line in ImageView on Android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, draw, swipe

I'd Like to know how to draw a Line on ImageView as user swipe their finger ?

Could any body explain this ? Or perhaps any Link to get start on this.

Comment: you want to draw certain line or do something like paint on it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must have your own ImageView and override onDraw function. Use something like this

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView{

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, p);

    }

}
```

and in your main class create object `MyImageView`; and when you touch your display call the `update();` function

Comment: Hi george, did you mean with calling the update method on onTouch() event ? I'm sorry for asking to much, i'm new in this.

Comment: Yes, I mean it. No problem, you can ask how much you want))

Comment: You must override OnTouchListener and in you OnTouch function calling the invalidate

Comment: i have the same problem. and i had tried it.. but it doesnt work for me.. Actually i am new to this android envrmnmt.. Can u just demonstrate it? Or does i have to put my question once more with all my code?

Comment: OK. It works only 3 changes needed - first add `Paint p` as a property of the class, then initialize it in your class constructor, then move `super.onDraw(canvas);` **above** your drawing operations. This will allow you to draw over original image.

Answer (score 9):

This is a complete example of how you can draw green rectangle over another image:

```
package CustomWidgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * Allows to draw rectangle on ImageView.
 *
 * @author Maciej Nux Jaros
 */
public class DrawImageView extends ImageView {
    private Paint currentPaint;
    public boolean drawRect = false;
    public float left;
    public float top;
    public float right;
    public float bottom;

    public DrawImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        currentPaint = new Paint();
        currentPaint.setDither(true);
        currentPaint.setColor(0xFF00CC00);  // alpha.r.g.b
        currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (drawRect)
        {
            canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, currentPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

When you have this defined you can replace ImageView with above View (widget) for example:

```
<CustomWidgets.DrawImageView
    android:id="@+id/widgetMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/map_small"
/>
```

Then you can use this for example in touch event of the activity that controls the layout:

```
    mapImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            DrawImageView drawView = (DrawImageView) v;

            // set start coords
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                drawView.left = event.getX();
                drawView.top = event.getY();
            // set end coords
            } else {
                drawView.right = event.getX();
                drawView.bottom = event.getY();
            }
            // draw
            drawView.invalidate();
            drawView.drawRect = true;

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Of course you could make some getters and setters and other Java over-engineering routines ;-).

Answer (score 0):

For drawing the line the user actually drew you have to override the dispatchTouchEvent. From that event you can get the coordinates of the line and draw them in the onDraw as shown by george.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ApiDemos sample [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html).

By using this you can draw line on ImageView by touching on the screen.