# How to draw line on my own uploaded map in android

Tags: android, maps, android-canvas, draw, android-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw lines over ImageView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831642/how-to-draw-lines-over-imageview-on-android)

I'm trying to find out how to draw lines (which will be paths of an map) on a uploaded ImageView.
What i'm trying to do is upload an map on my app, and then draw lines to represent paths through this map.
I've just found how to do that using Google Maps's APIs. I'd like to upload my own map on it. 
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this may be a duplicate of [How to draw lines over ImageView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831642/how-to-draw-lines-over-imageview-on-android)

But in case it isn't, if I understand you correctly you want to draw lines on top of an ImageView dynamically to show paths which I believe can be accomplished with the [drawLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) method.

You'll probably need to override the onDraw method of the ImageView and keep a list of the points for the path.