# How to get the exact time Choreographer calls last onDraw callback (pixels change)?

Tags: android, image, timestamp

For a reaction time app, I'm trying to get the exact time when an image is displayed on the screen, after setting a new `ImageDrawable` on an `ImageView`.

Simply getting the time stamp after the image resource is set is not sufficiently accurate, because after `ImageView.setImageDrawable()` Android still renders the image and waits for the next screen refresh before the image is actually displayed.

To get closer to the actual display time, I so far extended ImageView to schedule a [`Choreographer.FrameCallBack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.FrameCallback.html) in `onDraw()`.

```
Choreographer.FrameCallback mFrameCallback = new Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
    @Override
    // From the documentation:
    // This method provides the time in nanoseconds 
    // when the frame started being rendered.
    public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
        displayedAt = frameTimeNanos;
    }
};
```

...

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Choreographer choreographer = Choreographer.getInstance();
    choreographer.postFrameCallback(mFrameCallback);
}
```

However this method only gives the time system began rendering upcoming frame leaving the question of when the final callback is serviced and the pixels updated still undetermined - how can we determine the end of all doFrame()'s?

Comment: Try the Hugo library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

Comment: why don't you take the system.currenttimemillis()  when image is displayed, and compare it with system.currenttimemillis() when user touches the screen

Comment: @Tony, this is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm just wondering where exactly I should call system.currenttimemillis() to get the time the image is displayed on the screen. Is there a method which gets called exactly when the image shows up on the screen (i.e. "when the pixels light up")?

Comment: can you share your code? when the user starts to "play"?, you could create the image view programmatically and add it to the view that you want, and that time you get the current time..when the user clicks on the image it calculates the difference and you can show it into a text for example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606140/how-to-get-when-an-imageview-is-completely-loaded-in-android

Look at the answer, inside the run you could get the current time

Comment: @Tony, thanks a lot for the answer! I am actually trying to get the exact time the image is displayed on the screen after a new drawable is set on an already existing ImageView (I edited my question). `ImageView.post()` gives me the time the ImageView is laid out, which already happens before the user starts to "play".