# Draw on an image

Tags: android

Here is my problem. I am currently working on an android application that is handling images. When the application first starts, I have a list of categories (Food, Transport, Emergency ...). So I click on a category for example Food. I find myself in the second activity where I have subcategories (Fruit, Meat, Fish ...). So let's say I click on Fruit. I end up in the third activity which displays images (like in a gridview) of different fruits. I can either click on a fruit to zoom it or I can drag & drop it to the bottom of the activity where I have 3 dropzone that are here for me to create a sequence of images and save it.

So back to my problem, when I zoom on an image I want to be able to add a drawing feature. I want to be able to draw on the image when I click on the menu button of the phone and when I select "Draw". I tried to draw on an image but the drawing lines are always going underneath the pictures so I can't see them. Besides, I want to be able to save the image afterwards and I can't seem to find a way to my problem.

Could someone help me please?

I tried using BitmapFactory but it got me nowhere...

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw text On image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320392/how-to-draw-text-on-image)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use search:

[How to draw text On image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320392/how-to-draw-text-on-image)
[How to draw a Line in ImageView on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178896/how-to-draw-a-line-in-imageview-on-android)
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+Draw+on+an+image