# Image Editing with rotate ,zoom and drawing

Tags: android, paint

I want to make an Image editing app.For now I am able to drag,rotate and zoom View which is placed on an Image to be edited.Now I want to implement draw line as user want just like Pencil on that Image.I have googled a lot but still not get what I want.Please help me if anyone have idea about it.Thanks in advance.
I am using this code to Rotate,Zoom and Drag to image:[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android)

Comment: check this tutorial: [Android Gestures - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178896/how-to-draw-a-line-in-imageview-on-android Also the title is misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have implemented almost every thing  Now you need to listen to the touch events for draw and draw lines according to the touches in your canvas

using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines%28float%5B%5D,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) for straight lines

and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) for any shaped lines

For smooth lines and further help [refer this](http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html)