# How to create a straight green line between 3 image view in android

Tags: android

My requirement is to draw a straight line between three image view in android. Please some one give any solution or send me any source code. I am sending a image please have a look.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKPFh.png)

Comment: Are that three horizontal images fixed? If so then just put one view with green background color on top of it.

Comment: No the match images not always comes horizontally. They may comes vertically or diagonally or reverse v shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could place transparent `ImageViews` over your pictures, and if there is a winning pattern, draw the line on the `ImageViews`. Maybe this help you as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179075/7325737

Comment: Without any code, it's difficult to help you... Edit your question and add your code, this would be much easier to help you

Comment: Yes now I can draw lines of the transparent image view but the problem is it not place in exact position. I think the fruits images are not generating exact   coordinate. Please tell me how can I get exact image coordinate of the screen.